# I have a client that would like a multistep form built with Next.js, TypeScript, and PlanetScale. What would be the best way to do this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I am being tasked with making the UI of a multistep form using Next.js, TypeScript, and Tailwind CSS but I am very much a junior and outside of contact form or a simple register/sign in/sign out form UI I don't have much experience with forms.

I would love any suggestions on the best way to achieve this for an MVP.

The two options that I've seemingly come across is either building one from scratch, something like Web Dev Simplified's version with React and a custom hook, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDCBSnWkuH0, or doing something utilizing React Hook Form. I came across articles like this, https://claritydev.net/blog/build-a-multistep-form-with-react-hook-form, and this, https://claritydev.net/blog/advanced-multistep-forms-with-react.

I also thought to maybe try to do something like having a shell component that dynamically generates inputs needed based on some sort of Fields.tsx file. Iterating over data like this for example with a `.map()` -

```
export const userFields = [
  {
    label: 'First Name',
    type: 'text',
    name: 'firstName',
    autoFocus: true,
    required: true,
  },
  { label: 'Last Name', type: 'text', name: 'lastName', required: true },
  { label: 'Age', type: 'number', name: 'age', required: true, min: 1 },
];

export const accountFields = [
  {
    label: 'Email',
    type: 'email',
    name: 'email',
    autoFocus: true,
    required: true,
  },
  { label: 'Password', type: 'password', name: 'password', required: true },
];
```

But I'm wondering if that's not the best practice because some forms will have simple inputs, some will have things like a data picker, some might include conditionally rendering inputs based on whether a box is checked or not, etc. There's some diversity there in what each step will have of the 15-20 steps.

Also, is storing the data and steps in state or having a route based form better practice?

Would love any/all feedback and suggestions on how to proceed with this. Thank you.